# Add a pixel tag in all our emails

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have a use case I'm not able to solve.

Marketing team would like to add a pixel tag ( a line of HTML) in all our next emails sendings.
I'd like to NOT have to modify each email 1 by 1.

I was wondering if there is a possibility to add, at an account level, some code to all our emails ?

I was looking at Headers and Footers in Email > Admin > Account Settings but I'm not sure how it works.
And with this solution, if it works as I imagine, what I'll put in this section will be sent imedialty to all our emails (transactional and commercial), no ? I'd prefer to be sure that I won't send bad stuff in our emails...

Also, Header and Footers seems to be linked to the Can Spam regulations, and I don't have anymore this business rule activated on my account.
I don't know if this has an impact. Do you know ?

I hope you can help me, tell me if I'm not clear on some points !

Thanks in advance !

David

Comment: are you using templates? they would be the typical place for putting such more or less "global" data into a lot of emails - yet not necessarily all emails - centrally.

Comment: Hi Jonas, thank you. No we're using HTML emails. It seem Header&Footer can be a good solution, I'm trying to test it (but test in prod...) and for now it's not working, nothing is displayed in my emails. I'll let you know if I find someting with this feature.